# how i can take backup of file on UNIX-AIX?

Tags: backup, unix, command-line-interface, aix

how i can take backup of file on UNIX-AIX ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean. Backing up a file could be as simple as copying it somewhere else.

```
cp myfile /my/backups/myfile.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

dump/restore if you use tape. Otherwise use tar.
Bacula and Amanda automate backup, But need time for their adjustment and learning.

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 included ways of backing up a file in AIX, the "backup" command, and the Unix standard "tar" command.

To backup a file with tar run:

```
tar cvf /tmp/backup.tar ./path/to/originalfile
```

To restore the contents of the tar file back to the original location run:

```
cd /
tar xvf /tmp/backup.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a backup copy for a list of files:

```
prompt> # backup -ivf /dev/rmt0 file1 file2 file3 ...
```

if you want to backup a filesystem:

```
prompt> # backup -0 -u -f /dev/rmt0 / ( or any other filesystem )
```

later you´ld restore them using the restore command.